# What's the difference between [quadrature] and [approximate-integration]?

Tags: discussion, tag-management

The [quadrature](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadrature)  tag is described as "Quadrature refers to techniques in numerical integration, such as Riemann sum approximations, Simpson's rule and Gaussian quadrature." [approximate-integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximate-integration)  is described as "Use this tag for questions related to approximate integration, which constitutes a broad family of algorithms for calculating the numerical value of a definite integral."

Is there any difference between these two tags? If not, should they be made tag synonyms?

Comment: I guess it's clear that quadrature schemes (which typically use linear combinations of function evaluations, i.e. weighted point values) are a subset of approximate integration schemes.  I don't recall seeing a Question about an approximate integration scheme that was not a quadrature scheme, but I'll take a quick look.

Comment: By the numbers there is not a lot of overlap in usage of the two tags:  130 for quadrature, 205 for approximate-integration, and 9 for using both tags.  It seems to me that while Questions tagged quadrature are somewhat focused on basic *schemes* of numerical integration, the approximate-integration tag takes in problems about convergence of a sequence of integrals and some other aspects that are not just about the particular numerical schemes.

Comment: In fact, the word "quadrature" by itself can also be used for evaluating an integral by non-numerical means.  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quadrature.html

Comment: @GEdgar Then is it useful to have a tag for such an imprecisely defined term?

Comment: My impression is that "quadrature" usually refers to a numerical integration scheme that is based on some sort of (possibly piecewise) polynomial interpolation. With this interpretation, Monte Carlo and quasi-Monte Carlo methods are not quadrature methods.